# Changing property after specific time in ASP Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I'm working on a subscription-based system developed using Asp Core 3 MVC and Sql Server. The payment is handled externally, not linked to the application in any way. All I need to do in the application is to check the user's status, that is managed by an admin. When a user registers the status will be **Pending**, when the admin approves the user, **Approval Date** will be saved in the database, and the status will be changed to **Approved**.

The tricky thing for me is that I want the application to wait for 365 days before it changes the user status to **Expired**.  I've no idea from where to start this part and would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way i can think of without using [hosted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) is to add a check on user login that subtracts the approval date from today's date and check if the difference is equal or greater than 365 days

Something like this:

```cs
if ((DateTime.Now - user.ApprovalDate).TotalDays >= 365)
{
    //Mark the user as expired...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't trigger a background thread from your main application code.

The correct way to do this is with a [background worker process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) that has been designed specifically for this scenario.

ASP.NET Core 3 has a project type that is specifically for this, and will continue to run the back ground and can be used for all of your maintenance tasks. You can create a worker process using `dotnet new worker -o YourProjectName` or selecting **Worker Service** from the project selection window in Visual Studio.

Within that service you can then create a routine that will be used to determine if the user has expired. Encapsulate this logic in a class that makes testing easy.

Working repl has been posted [here](https://repl.it/@cuperman/ItchyNegativeBundledsoftware).

```
using System;

public class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    var user = new User(){ ApprovedDate =  DateTime.Today };
    Console.WriteLine (UserHelper.IsUserExpired(user));
    
    // this should be false
    user = new User(){ ApprovedDate =  DateTime.Today.AddDays(-180) };
    Console.WriteLine (UserHelper.IsUserExpired(user));
    
    // this should be false
    user = new User(){ ApprovedDate =  DateTime.Today.AddDays(-365) };
    Console.WriteLine (UserHelper.IsUserExpired(user));

    // this should be true
    user = new User(){ ApprovedDate =  DateTime.Today.AddDays(-366) };
    Console.WriteLine (UserHelper.IsUserExpired(user));
  }
}

public class User {
  public DateTime ApprovedDate {get; set;}
}

public static class UserHelper
{
  public static bool IsUserExpired(User user){
    //... add all the repective logic in here that you need, for example;
    return (DateTime.Today - user.ApprovedDate.Date).TotalDays > 365;
  }
}
```